# Adding reference to AjaxControlToolkit to web.config file

Tags: web-config, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm trying to add some ajax controls to my page:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="lnkDelete" CommandName="DeleteCity" CssClass="rowbutton" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("cityid") %>' Text="Delete" />

<ajax:ConfirmButtonExtender runat="server" ID="confirm_Delete" TargetControlID="lnkDelete" ConfirmText="Deleting a city will delete all Suburbs, DICs and Appointments associated with it.&#10;Do you want to continue?">
</ajax:ConfirmButtonExtender>
```

I've checked a couple of questions on SO and I found [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/1174924.aspx) as well, but still not having any luck getting pages to accept the new tag.

When I register the AjaxControlToolkit on Page level, it works, but when I add it to the web.config file, it still can't find the server tag:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>`) it works, but I'd rather not do this for every page that I need to use ajax on.
```

**Note:** Registering this way doesn't work if it is done on the master page.

I have the following in my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
-->
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <pages styleSheetTheme="Default">
          <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="ajax" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
          </controls>      
        </pages>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Have I done something wrong? What's the right way to do it here?

In case it might be important, I'm using AjaxControlToolkit version 4.1.51116

Answer (score 1):

Turns out simply rebuilding the solution sorted this one out.

I persisted the change to add the reference into the web.config file and rebuilt the solution.

Everything works okay now